# Redux pass / mock dispatch actions while testing higher order components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, redux-thunk, react-testing-library

While I am trying to test an Redux connected react component, I am unable to provide  .Below is the code for my connected react component :

```
    MyComponent.jsx
    
    class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    
    componentWillMount (){
    
    }
    
    
    componentDidMount () {
    
    setTimeOut (()=>{
    changeValue('personName' , 'something',someVar)
    
    },2000);
    
    }
    
    }
export default MyComponent

    
    index.jsx
    
    import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
    const mapStateToProps = state => (
    {
    rootState : state 
    info : state.someInfo
    }
    )
    
    const mapDispatchProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    changeValue : change,
    resetValue : reset
    
    },dispatch)
    
    export default compose (connect (mapStateToProps,mapDispatchProps),injector,theme.wizard({}))(
    connect(state => ({
    values : selector (state, 'vehicleName', 'address','personName')
    }))
    )(MyComponent)

MyComponent.Test.js

import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
jest.useFakeTimers();
describe('test1', ()=>{
it('test for componentDidMount' , ()=>{
const middlewares = []
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)
const initialState = {changeValue : (x,y,z)=> console.log(x)};
  const store = mockStore(initialState);
var component = shallow (<Provider store = {store}><MyComponent /></Provider>);
component.update();
jest.runAllTimers();
})
}
```

When I run this I get ***error : changeValue is not a function*** , How can I pass/Mock changeValue function  in the test to resolve this error.

Comment: Your `MyComponent` (*maybe*) composition doesn't quite look correct... the second `connect` isn't decorating anything. It also appears you are testing the undecorated `MyComponent` component.

Comment: updated the snippet

Comment: @DrewReese Updated the Snippet. Please help.

Comment: It still appears you are testing the the undecorated `MyComponent` component (MyComponent.jsx), i.e. it isn't connected to the redux store. You can likely just provide mocked props to it directly. Perhaps you intended to import the default export component from index.js?

Comment: I mocked the props but I am getting the issue while componentDidMount gets called , it expects the function changeValue to be there, but I am unable to provide the same. Also  I cannot change the code that's the constraint.

Comment: @DrewReese  export default compose is already there is index.jsx

Comment: `changeValue` is a prop passed to `MyComponent`, it is trivial to pass a mock callback to the undecorated component (this is also how I prefer testing my UI code). In your test, you `import MyComponent from './MyComponent'`, which component is this? This looks to be the same one you import in `index.jsx` in your snippet. Is `changeValue` correctly accessed from props in `MyComponent`? Please update your question to include [Minimal, **Complete**, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code examples, preferably styled in a more readable manner.